# autocomplete returns all values

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, webapi

I am using autocomplete with input but it returns all of the values even when I type wrong words!
here is my html and jquery 
it seems I am missing something or adding something and my api returns the following json:

```js
var product={
"productId": "98fe4407-1069-430c-38e3-08d7f0691c31",
"memberId": "f32598fe-0967-428c-a66a-08d7ef224f73",
"member": null,
"name": "فلتر قهوة",
"nameAr": "Filter",
"categoryId": 2,
"category": {
"categoryId": 2,
"member": null,
"memberId": "f32598fe-0967-428c-a66a-08d7ef224f73",
"name": "Materials ",
"nameAr": "ادوات",
"details": ""
},
"description": "Classic fresh filter coffee served with fresh cream",
"sku": "0",
"barcode": "0",
"quantity": 968,
"warningQuantity": null,
"unitId": 4,
"units": {
"unitId": 4,
"member": null,
"memberId": "f32598fe-0967-428c-a66a-08d7ef224f73",
"name": "Piece"
},
"priceSell": 9,
"pricePurchase": 5,
"inventoryStatusId": 1,
"inventoryStatus": {
"inventoryStatusId": 1,
"member": null,
"memberId": null,
"status": "ava",
"statusAr": "متوفر"
},
"storeId": "628ecc6f-0970-4595-1e10-08d7ef2328b9",
"store": {
"storeId": "628ecc6f-0970-4595-1e10-08d7ef2328b9",
"name": "Dr3eH",
"nameAr": "الدرعية",
"address": "الدرعية",
"memberId": "f32598fe-0967-428c-a66a-08d7ef224f73",
"member": null,
"typeId": 2,
"storeType": null
},
"vendorId": "66a4b78b-c554-46f5-4af7-08d7ef233708",
"vendor": {
"vendorId": "66a4b78b-c554-46f5-4af7-08d7ef233708",
"name": "اي شي",
"memberId": "f32598fe-0967-428c-a66a-08d7ef224f73",
"member": null,
"description": "",
"phone": "88",
"email": "",
"address": "",
"address2": ""
},
"hasIngredients": false,
"isForSale": true,
"isIngrefient": false,
"imageId": 7,
"tempImage": {
"imgId": 7,
"imgPath": "732388ad-1069-414b-a273-5ff9bcd4cd2fFilter.png"
}
}



$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtBarcode").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/api/products/0/" + StoreId +
                        "/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/",
                type: "GET",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            nameAr: item.nameAr,
                            quantity: item.quantity,
                            id: item.productId,
                            price: item.priceSell
                        }
                    }))
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 0,
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#txtBarcode").val(ui.item.nameAr);
            return false;
        },
        delay: 100,
        position: {
            my: 'left top',
            at: 'left bottom',
            collision: 'none',
            offset: '0'
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log("form Autocomplete select " + ui.item.id);
            var pId = ui.item.id
            document.getElementById("addToInvoiceItem").onclick = function() {
                addToSlectedItemsData(pId, 1)
            };
            return false;
        }
    })
    .data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        console.log("form Autocomplete.data " + item.id);
        return $("<li>")
            .append("<div><b>" + item.nameAr + "</b><br>Quantity: " +
                item.quantity + " Price:  " + item.priceSell + "</div>")
            .appendTo(ul);
        };
    });
```

```html
<input type="text" 
    onchange="selectItemList()" 
    id="txtBarcode" 
    data-value-property="productId" 
    data-search-in="nameAr" 
    name="selectedItemName" 
    class="col-sm-12 custom-select" 
    placeholder="ادخل رقم المنتج او اسمة اورقم الباركود" />
```

I tried many ways to add the source and get the selected item ID but it seems every time I'm stuck with an error

Comment: Is this with jquery-ui? If yes, please add info.

Comment: Well, I would suggest you check if you are receiving the filtered params in your api or not. And also debug how are they being processed.

Comment: @wazz I am not using jquery-ui

Comment: @JamshaidKamran how do i know if it is filtered or not I mean where to see?

Comment: Well, to verify it, you should look at your API endpoint, `url: "/api/products/0/" + StoreId + "/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/"`

Comment: @JamshaidKamran ok, this returns all products from the api when  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 this means all products, and 0 means  means quantity should be more than 0

Comment: Well, this depends on your logic in the API, post your code if you need help on that.

Comment: I don't understand, the api returns all of the items to the source of the autocomplete function just as it is in the apove quistion.